# unable to compose actions when using parse.json

Tags: playframework

I have a working piece of code which takes a `json` request.

```
def signupUser = silhouette.UserAwareAction.async {...}
```

I want to use `parse.json` with the existing `Action` but I am unable to figure out how to do it.

I thought I could just write `def signupUser = Action(parse.json) {silhouette.UserAwareAction.async {` but I am getting error `cannot resolve overloaded method`.

I then changed the code to

```
Action.async(parse.json) {silhouette.UserAwareAction.async {
...
val body = request.body
}
```

but the request.body is still of type `AnyContent` instead of `JsValue`

Am I not using composition correctly? Why is body of type `AnyContent`?

Answer (score 0):

Action builder and parsers are distinct concepts which play hand in hand out of the box. I would expect this to work:

```
def signupUser = silhouette.UserAwareAction.async(parse.json) {...}
```